# gdb macro for network programming

Tags: c, network-programming, gdb

I have never used gdb macros before. I am interested in finding out if there are any macros out there for network programming debugging.

Specifically, I have a bunch of structures that contain IP addresses and it is a real pain to keep having to convert them manually as a "watcher" when I want to see the string address of the IP address (172.x.x.x). I was hoping there are some macros out there for converting in_addr and in_addr_t and sockaddr and all of those things to host strings.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply write you're own.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-gdb.html

^- review these examples. At the end you'll be able to write your own.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how useful this is for you, but you could have functions in your code that just dump the fields to human readable form and then call them from within gdb.  This might interfere with what you are doing but could be a start.  I'd suggest you go with gdb macros though.